# Is $K:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R:|x|^2=y^2\}$ a submanifold of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

> Is $K:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R:|x|^2=y^2\}$ a submanifold of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$?

I guess that no, but Im not sure how I can prove it. I know that the derived sets $K\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and $\{(x,y)\in K:y>0\}$ are $n$-dimensional smooth submanifolds of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

My work so far: first observe that $K$ is not open in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ because no one of it points is an interior point. Thus $K$ cannot be a $(n+1)$-dimensional $\Bbb C^q$ submanifold of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ for any $q\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}​$ because if $g\in{\rm Diff}^q(U,V)​$ for some open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ then $U\cap K$ is not open and $g^{-1}(V)\neq U\cap K$ because $g^{-1}(V)​$ need to be open.

However I dont have a clue about how to show that $K$ is not a $k$-dimensional sub manifold for any other dimension. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

EDITION: because projections of product topologies are open maps then if $V$ is an open ball in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and $k\le n$ then $V\cap(\Bbb R^k\times\{0\})\cong V'$ for some open ball $V'\subset\Bbb R^k$.

Thus, WLOG, suppose there is some $h\in{\rm Diff}^0(U,V)$ for some open balls $U$ and $V$ centered at zero of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, then if $h(U\cap K)=V\cap(\Bbb R^k\times\{0\})$, for some $k\le n$, then $U\cap K\cong U'$ for some open ball $U'$ centered at zero of $\Bbb R^k$.

Hence to solve this exercise, if Im not wrong, it would be enough to show that $U\cap K$ is not homeomorphic to any open ball in $\Bbb R^k$ for any $k\le n$. It seems easier to think about the continuity of $h^{-1}$ and $n=1$, then it is easy to show that $U\cap K$ cannot be homemorphic to any open interval of $\Bbb R$. However I dont know exactly how to show this in the general setting.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How many connected components does $K\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ have? (Consider the $n=1$ and $n>1$ cases separately.) Is this the behavior you expect from a locally Euclidean space?

Comment: I dont know what is a component. But I know that for $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R,\, x\mapsto |x|$ then $K$ is the graph of $f$ and $-f$ together.